# Laravel, eloquent and foreach in controller

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm new in Laravel and I'm curious about one thing. I have 3 database tables: posts, comments, replies. I want to make a simple delete from each. But obviously post has many comments and comments has many replies. Whole thing is about these replies. Seems like I can't reach them.

I have properly working relations between tables.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;
use App\Comment;
use App\Reply;
use App\Traffic;
use Image;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class PostsController extends Controller
{

  //few others things here...

  public function destroy($id) //$id is an id of post
    {
        // Select Post and comments of post
        $post = Post::find($id);
        $comments = Comment::where('post_id', $id);        

        //remove image (working fine)
        Storage::delete('public/img/' . $post->image);

        // delete all replies of post comments <<< Here is the issue. Can I even do like this?
            foreach ($comments as $comment) {
                $post_comment_reply = Reply::where('comment_id', $comment->id);
                $post_comment_reply->delete();
            }

            // delete post record (working fine)
            $post->delete();

            //delete comments of post (working fine)
            $comments->delete();

            // return to user profile (working fine)
            return redirect('/home')->with('success', 'Post has been deleted');
    }
```

Comment: This should be automatic at the database level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an even easier way to do so.. if you just add a database constraint to the foreign key in the replies table to the comment..

```
$table->unsignedInteger('comment_id');

$table->foreign('comment_id')->references('id')->on('comments')
    ->onDelete('cascade');
```

The last part: `onDelete('cascade')` ensures that all the replies will be deleted once a comment has been deleted :) so you don't have to manually do that in the application layer.

Let me know if it makes sense :)

Comment: What to type for migration roll back?

Comment: If this was your last migration that you have run.. then `php artisan migrate:rollback` will delete the table, then `php artisan migrate` will create it again. Otherwise just add a new migration in which you will drop the foreign key first if you had one, and add the new one as I've shown you above.

Comment: Thanks, it's good idea to rollback the table and create it again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting the replies in a loop, you can delete them all at once:

```php
$comments = Comment::where('post_id', $id);
$comment_ids = $comments->pluck('id');

Reply::whereIn('comment_id', $comment_ids)->delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong in your code is that you create a db query but does not execute it:

```
// You forgot the ->get() following the where statement
foreach ($comments as $comment) 
    $post_comment_reply = Reply::where('comment_id', $comment->id)->get();
    $post_comment_reply->delete();
}
```

However the code altogether is not quite optimal, you could make it directly on database level with onDelete('cascade'), or simply create a request to delete the replies without retrieving them and reducing the number of query to the db, like such:

```
foreach ($comments as $comment) 
    Reply::where('comment_id', $comment->id)->delete();
}
```

One step further reducing db queries like suggested above:

```
Reply::whereIn('comment_id', $comments->pluck('id'))->delete();
```

Comment: Yes I confirm the last one it's working. But now I'm considering to do this on db level as Nakov showed. Thank you!

Comment: What I have written is not the database level deletes. nakov's answer does the database level deletes. I hope you understood the difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the relations via Laravel, you have to override the `boot` function.

Override the `boot()` on your Comment model like

```
protected static function boot()
    {
        static::deleting(function (Comment $model) {
            $model->replies()->delete();
        });

        parent::boot();
    }
```

This will delete all the replies associated to a comment when that comment is deleted via eloquent.

Comment: I use it this way just because I want more control on the deletes. Database cascade deletes are definitely an option you should consider.